# Can I use a .bib file instead of adding an in-page bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am working on an article for a Springer paper. The Latex template shows the bibliography on the same page as I am writing the article. However, I prefer having a separate .bib file to add my Bibtex reference.

Roughly, the file has the following structure:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{8}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the setup to work with a separate .bib file to which I refer?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Springer gives a file with instructions about it.
First you should load the package to use the bibliography functions:
`\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}`

At the end of your document you should put the instructions to find your .bib file and the bibliography style file

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic3}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

(I used spbasic3 style that is a common Springer style)

Of course, on Google you will find plenty of more detailed instructions about it.